# Angular / Typescript Nested Objects (Model)

Tags: angular, typescript, object, model

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'applicants' of undefined
```

I am trying to run the following at component startup

```
application: application;
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.application.applicants[0].type = "1";    <-- don't think this is right
}
```

These are the two classes I created

```
export class application{
  applicants: applicants[];
  constructor(applicants: applicants[]){this.applicants = applicants;}
}

export class applicants{
  type: String;
  constructor(type: String){this.type = type;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class application before you try and access the applicants. Because of how you have the constructor you will also need to instantiate an array of applicants. Try:

```
applicants: applicants[] = [new applicants("Applicant1"), new applicants("Applicant2"), new applicants("Applicant3")]
application: application = new application(applicants)
```